# Propagate exception from C++ constructor with cython

Tags: python, c++, exception, cython

I want to raise an exception in C++ class constructor if some parameters are invalid, e.g., do `PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "Error occurred")`. Unfortunately, it does not propagate correctly, and I get `SystemError: <class 'testlib.foo.Foo'> returned a result with an error set` instead. Is it even possible to make it work inside a constructor?

Several concerns:

- All of the logic should be in the C++ class without spreading into `.pyx` files.
- Validation should happen inside the constructor, so that it is not needed to call separate `init()` method after object creation.
- It should be possible to raise not only some standard exceptions, but any custom.

**setup.py**

```
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from Cython.Distutils import Extension
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(
    name='testlib',
    python_requires='~=3.7.0',
    packages=find_packages('src'),
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
    ext_modules=cythonize(
        [
            Extension(
                'testlib.foo',
                ['src/testlib/foo.pyx', 'src/testlib/c_foo.cpp'],
                extra_compile_args=['-std=c++11'], language='c++',
            )
        ], language_level='3'
    )
)
```

**src/testlib/c_foo.h**

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN

#include <Python.h>

namespace foo {
    class Foo {
        public:
            Foo();
            ~Foo();
    };
}

#endif
```

**src/testlib/c_foo.cpp**

```
#include "c_foo.h"


namespace foo {

    Foo::Foo() {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "Error occurred");
    }
    Foo::~Foo() {}
}
```

**src/testlib/c_foo.pxd**

```
cdef extern from "c_foo.h" namespace "foo":
    cdef cppclass Foo:
        Foo()
```

**src/testlib/foo.pyx**

```
from .c_foo cimport Foo as CFoo

cdef class Foo:
    cdef CFoo *c_foo

    def __cinit__(self):
        self.c_foo = new CFoo()

    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.c_foo
```

**tests/test_foo.py**

```
import pytest
from testlib.foo import Foo


def test_foo():
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        Foo()    # SystemError: <class 'testlib.foo.Foo'> returned a result with an error set
```

First two concerns can be resolved by doing `throw std::invalid_argument("Some error")` together with `Foo() except +` in `c_foo.pxd`, but it does not work for arbitrary python exceptions.

Comment: Have you tried `except *` (which means any Python exception can be set, no way to tell from the return type)? There may be specific issues with empty c++ constructors though.

Comment: Are the possible approaches described in http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#exceptions not sufficient (by either choosing the appropriate C++ exception, or trying to assign a "exception translation" function or converting all exception to some specific one on Py side).

Comment: @DavidW yes, I tried it and it gives `Exception clause not allowed for function returning Python object`

Comment: That sounds like a bug. The complication is that any stack allocated C++ objects are initialized at the start of a Cython function where it isn't really possible to add exception checks, so it's probably quite difficult to do much useful with it.

Comment: @DanM. hmm, I guess it is adequate solution if there are no more straightforward alternatives.

Comment: You could look at a static factory function with `except *`  rather than the constructor?

Comment: @DavidW also a good solution, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, be aware that this has the potential to go a quite wrong. Python scoping rules are different from C++ scoping rules, and Cython largely follows Python scoping rules. Consider

```
# distutils: language=c++

cdef extern from "something.hpp":
    cdef cppclass C:
        C()

def f(x):
    cdef C c
    if x>0:
        c = C()
```

`c` *must* be available whatever branch you take, and thus is default initialized at the start of the function:

```
CYTHON_UNUSED C __pyx_v_c;
```

This default initialization won't have the standard exception handling around it (in principle it probably could for a Python exception like in this case, but it'd be very difficult to handle C++ exception in the constructor and make code that compiles in C++).

Therefore if you have any stack-allocated variables of your class you risk putting Cython into a state where an exception is set, but it believes one shouldn't be.

---

With that said, I think the way to do this is probably to use a static factory function. Cython does understand exception specifications on these (it not understanding an `except *` on a c++ constructor is probably a small bug...)

```
# distutils: language=c++

cdef extern from *:
    """
    class Foo {
        public:
            Foo() {
                PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "Error occurred");
            }
            ~Foo() {}
            
            static Foo getFoo() {
                return Foo();
            }
    };
    """
    cdef cppclass Foo:
        Foo()
        @staticmethod
        Foo getFoo() except *

def f():
    Foo.getFoo()
```

This code generates the following C++ code from Cython:

```
Foo::getFoo(); if (unlikely(PyErr_Occurred())) __PYX_ERR(0, 23, __pyx_L1_error)
```

and thus does what you'd expect - it checks for the C++ exception and handles it as expected.

---

I still think this is a bad idea.